# Changing directories & files to lowercase 'already exists' error

Tags: bash

I'm using the code:

```
echo "Changing Directories to lowercase..."
find -type d | rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
echo "Changing Files to lowercase..."
find -type f | rename -f 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

to change directories and files to lowercase.

In the test folder I have three files, lower, MixEd & UPPER. When I run the above code I get the following error:

MixEd not renamed: mixed already exists
UPPER not renamed: upper already exists

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `find` doing there? Why do you `|` pipe the output of find? Do you have [PERL rename](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_perl_oneliners/perl-rename-command.html) or [util linux rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html for `nocaseglob` (and possibly `nocasematch`) then see if you have either or both of those set or just make sure they aren't set with `shopt -u`.

Comment: What filesystem is this on? (Especially: is the filesystem case sensitive, or not?)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I'd just use a shell loop as it's trivial to write, clear and you can control everything you want it to do in the sunny-day and the rainy-day cases, e.g.:

```
while IFS= read -r old; do

    new="${old,,}"
    canMove=1
    if [[ -f "$new" ]]; then
        if [[ -s "$new" ]]; then
            printf '%s already exists and is not empty, skipping.\n' "$new" >&2
            canMove=0
        else
            printf '%s already exists but is empty, overwriting.\n' "$new" >&2
        fi
    fi
    (( canMove == 1 )) && mv -- "$old" "$new"

done < <(find . -type f)
```

Comment: @pjh ah, you're right, fixed now thanks. I normally avoid break/continue as they're the slightly less obnoxious cousins of "goto" - I should've stuck to that :-).

Answer (score 1):

You missed `-depth` switch if you rename path:

> The -depth option for example makes find traverse the file system in a depth-first order

And if you use files in current directory this is sufficient:

```
$ ls 
lower  MixEd  UPPER
$ rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' ./*
$ ls
lower  mixed  upper
```

using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895).